# Spark Conditional join where a column value is between two column values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a messy df that looks like

```scala
val df = Seq(
    ("id1", "2020-08-02 16:42:00", "2020-08-02 16:45:00", "item1", 1),
    ("id1", "2020-08-02 16:43:00", "2020-08-02 16:44:00", "item2", 0),
    ("id1", "2020-08-02 16:44:00", "2020-08-02 16:45:00", "item1", 0),
    ("id1", "2020-08-02 16:45:00", "2020-08-02 16:47:00", "item3", 0),
    ("id1", "2020-08-02 16:47:00", "2020-08-02 16:51:00", "item4", 0),
    ("id1", "2020-08-02 16:51:00", "2020-08-02 16:52:00", "item3", 0))
.toDF("id", "start_time", "end_time", "item_id", "flag")

df.show()

+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+----+
| id|         start_time|           end_time|item_id|flag|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+----+
|id1|2020-08-02 16:42:00|2020-08-02 16:45:00|  item1|   1|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:43:00|2020-08-02 16:44:00|  item2|   0|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:44:00|2020-08-02 16:45:00|  item1|   0|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:45:00|2020-08-02 16:47:00|  item3|   0|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:47:00|2020-08-02 16:51:00|  item4|   0|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:51:00|2020-08-02 16:52:00|  item3|   0|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+----+
```

Notice that the first row has `start_time = 16:42:00` and `end_time = 16:45:00`, and the next two rows has a `start_time` that are between the `start_time` and `end_time` of the first row. I already have a column `flag` that detects when such an occurrence is observed.
In this case, I want to keep the first row and remove the next two rows. I am just using a sample, but such an occurrence can be seen multiple times.

So the output I want is

```scala
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
| id|         start_time|           end_time|item_id|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
|id1|2020-08-02 16:42:00|2020-08-02 16:45:00|  item1|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:45:00|2020-08-02 16:47:00|  item3|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:47:00|2020-08-02 16:51:00|  item4|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:51:00|2020-08-02 16:52:00|  item3|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

I tried to create a different df filtering just rows where `flag = 1` and doing a conditional join

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")

val dfFiltered = df.filter("flag == 1")

df.join(dfFiltered, 
  (df("id") == dfFiltered("id")) && 
  (df("start_time") > dfFiltered("start_time")) && 
  (df("start_time") < dfFiltered("end_time")))
.show()
```

but it returns wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to solve this without joining - you can get the maximum end_time over the previous rows, and filter away the rows where start < max(end_time).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "last_end", 
    max(
        when($"flag" === 1, $"end_time")
    ).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("start_time").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1))
).filter("last_end is null or start_time >= last_end").drop("last_end")

df2.show
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+----+
| id|         start_time|           end_time|item_id|flag|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+----+
|id1|2020-08-02 16:42:00|2020-08-02 16:45:00|  item1|   1|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:45:00|2020-08-02 16:47:00|  item3|   0|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:47:00|2020-08-02 16:51:00|  item4|   0|
|id1|2020-08-02 16:51:00|2020-08-02 16:52:00|  item3|   0|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+----+
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `left_anti` join:

```
val result = df.as("df").drop("flag")
  .join(
    dfFiltered.as("filter"),
    ($"df.id" === $"filter.id") &&
      ($"df.start_time" > $"filter.start_time") &&
      ($"df.start_time" < $"filter.end_time"),
    "left_anti"
  )

result.show
//+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
//| id|         start_time|           end_time|item_id|
//+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
//|id1|2020-08-02 16:42:00|2020-08-02 16:45:00|  item1|
//|id1|2020-08-02 16:45:00|2020-08-02 16:47:00|  item3|
//|id1|2020-08-02 16:47:00|2020-08-02 16:51:00|  item4|
//|id1|2020-08-02 16:51:00|2020-08-02 16:52:00|  item3|
//+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

Or with a correlated subquery in `WHERE` using `EXISTS`:

```
val result = spark.sql("""
  select * 
  from   df t1
  where  not exists(
          select 1 from df t2 
          where t1.id = t2.id 
          and t2.flag = 1
          and t1.start_time > t2.start_time 
          and t1.start_time < t2.end_time
        )
""")
```